# windows alert - DriverToaster.exe parameter incorrect

Tags: windows-10

I got this windows 10 alert suddenly. drivertoaster.exe found 0 on google. anyone familiar with this?

[image: windows alert]

Comment: I recieved the same error. It appears to be caused by a windows app. My computer recently added the app "Dell Support Assist". I think that might be the cause.

Comment: I had the same alert today, again on a Dell machine. I note that at about the same time the icons on my Desktop moved down a couple of spaces, like can happen if you change screen resolution. Perhaps the display driver is involved.

Comment: Same on my wife's notebook 5 min ago. Strange that many people experience this approximately at the same time. Maybe something related to expired certificate that was used to sign the driver?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1234341/drivertoaster-exe-is-reporting-that-the-parameter-is-incorrect/1234342#1234342